# Is there a set $A$ such that power set of $A $ has a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: set-theory

Has this statement any relation with continuum hypothesis ?

Comment: What do you know about set theory so far? This is relatively easy if you know that any subset of the natural numbers is either itself countable or finite. (From there, you can proceed noting that, were $f:P(A)\rightarrow\mathbb N$ such a bijection, then the map $g:A\rightarrow\mathbb N$ with $g(x)=f(\{x\})$ would have its image be a subset of $\mathbb N$ equinumerous to $A$.)

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close - this is a reasonable question, especially if we work in ZF rather than ZFC.

Comment: @Noah: This post is horrible in any standard you can expect. It uses the title to ask the question and the body as a continuation for a remark, it has no context as to what the OP knows or does not know about set theory, and it is fact a duplicate. I am more than certain that I have answered this question recently as well, perhaps as part of a larger discussions, but it was there. So no effort, no context, no quality. Definitely close worthy.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's certainly poorly formatted, and being a duplicate of course makes it close-worthy. If it weren't a duplicate, though, I'd give it the benefit of the doubt just because I think it would produce valuable answers (as the question it's a duplicate of has). Keeping in mind that plenty of homework questions which display no attempted effort are left open, and answered, I would side with keeping this question open (although, if it had occurred to me :P, I would have massively edited it). I might be being too generous though, it's late and I'm tired :P

Comment: Speaking of tired: I somehow managed to confuse $\mathcal{P}(A)$ with $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$. I've deleted that very silly answer and I'm going to bed now.

Answer (score 7):

If $A$ is not countable, then $\mathscr P(A)$ is also not countable. Indeed, since $A \subset \mathscr P(A)$, it is clear that $|A| \leq |\mathscr P(A)|$, so $\mathscr P(A)$ must also not be countable.

If $A$ is countable, then $\mathscr P(A)$ has cardinality of the continuum.

If $A$ is finite, say it has $n$ elements, then $\mathscr P(A)$ has $2^n$ elements, and thus is still finite.

So there does not exist such a set $A$.

The continuum hypothesis says there is no cardinality between the natural numbers ($\aleph_0$) and the continuum ($2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$), and the generalized continuum hypothesis says that $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha + 1}$, so this question does not have any real connection to it.

*N.B.* here the term "not countable" means not finite nor countable.

Comment: Is it trivial that a set is not finite means its cardinality is greater than or equals to that of natural no.?

Comment: @SubhasisRay this is trivial if we assume the axiom of choice; without AC, though, it can be false.

Comment: Thanks Noah Schweber, I have got the answer under the Qs. "Existence in ZF of a set with countable power set" which had posted in two years ago. "There is no cardinality between ℵ0 and ℵ1" and  "There is no cardinality between finite and ℵ0" ,-  this two statements sound similar. For this reason I have asked this question.